# MATHCAD for electronics circuit analysis usable for production testing

Tags: circuit-analysis, production-testing, nodal-analysis

Do anyone have any Idea how to use **MATHCAD** for **electronics circuit analysis**.

For example, can I find the Worst Case Analysis ( maximum and minimum values at testpoints) of a complex DC circuit for Battey Management including EMC filter circuits.

I guess this will give an more accurare voltage levels at every testpoints which in turn support PCB testing during series production.

Or any other suggestion to analyze the circuit for PCB testing during production line?

edit: I also want to check the values of all components at production line testing.

Thanks

Comment: Advanced circuit analysis programs have a long time been capable for statistical Monte Carlo analyses, temperature analyses and sensitivity calculations. Never heard? With them you can avoid equation writing errors.

Comment: To be frank, I have not heard of such. Can you give me one or two examples of such a program?

Comment: Spice is a common one.

Comment: PSpice software?

Comment: check https://resources.orcad.com/all-videos/pspice-monte-carlo-analysis

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but Mathcad is not "circuit aware".  That is, it cannot take a schematic, netlist, and BOM and do what you're asking, a WCA for example.

What you can do with Mathcad is to input the equations that define the various parameters that you're interested in, such a voltage error or gain error, give a range of values for the various things that contribute to those parameters (like resistance tolerance), and have it produce a range for the parameters you're interested in - the Monte Carlo analysis user287001 referred to.

Our power supply group uses Mathcad as part of their analysis for the switch mode power supplies (SMPSs) they design, to analyze things like over voltage and over current trip points, for instance.